# how to get rid of dual errors groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a validation for big file size in a try block, after throwing that error its again going and checking the null values of the other attributes of static constraints and throwing that error as well.

How to stop the flow after returning the first error?

here is the code

```
static constraints = {
        applicationName(blank: false, size: 1..25)
        applicationShortName(blank: false, size: 1..10)
        applicationImage(nullable: false, maxSize: MAX_SIZE)
        contentProviderId (
            validator: {
                if (it == 0) {
                    return ['notSelected']
                }
            }
        )
        customErrorMessage (
                validator: {
                    if ("fileToBig".equals(it)) {
                        return ['fileToBig']
                    }
                }
        )
    }

try {
            CommonsMultipartFile file = request.getFile('applicationImageUrl');

            logger.debug("POSTPROCESS: is file empty=${file.isEmpty()}")
            if(!file.isEmpty()) {

                try {


                        -- other logic


                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.warn("Failed to upload file - improper file type", ex)
                    return [];
                }

                logger.debug("Getting new image file")
                try {
                    -- logic

                    if (file.size <= MAX_SIZE) {
                        -- logic
                    } else {
                        customErrorMessage = "fileToBig"; ( ERROR FOR BIG FILE SIZE)


                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.warn("Failed to upload file", e)
                    customErrorMessage = "fileToBig";

                }
            } else {
                logger.debug("File was empty. Will check if there is a file in submission")
                if (submission.applicationImage != null && submission.applicationImage != []) {
                    logger.debug("submission contains applicationImage=${submission.applicationImage}")
                    this.applicationImage = submission.applicationImage;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.errors.reject("error","An error occured when uploading file. Please try again.");
            logger.error("Failed to upload file", e);
            return [];
        }

        --logic
        if (application != null) { //Application already exists!
            submission.applicationId = application.id;
            return [next: 10];
        }

        return [];
    }
```

after the big file size error, the application image is not set , so its throwing application image null error as well...

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this. Can you explain why you want to stop validation if this constraint is violated? Perhaps I can suggest another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: please check the edited question...please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom validator to your applicationImage field, to only check for null value if customErrorMessage field is not null.
This way you will only get applicationImage error in validation exception if customErrorMessage is not null.

In validator closure you have access to the value of the field being checked and to the whole object as well:

```
myField(validator: { val, obj -> return propertyName == "myField" })
```

Thus you can do something like this:

```
static constraints = {
        applicationName(blank: false, size: 1..25)
        applicationShortName(blank: false, size: 1..10)
        applicationImage(validator: {val, obj ->
            if (obj.customErrorMessage != null) {
                if (val == null) return ['imageNull']
                if (val.size() > MAX_SIZE) return ['tooLarge']
            }
        })
        contentProviderId (
            validator: {
                if (it == 0) {
                    return ['notSelected']
                }
            }
        )
        customErrorMessage (
                validator: {
                    if ("fileToBig".equals(it)) {
                        return ['fileToBig']
                    }
                }
        )
    }
```

Might need a tweak in error messages but I hope you get my point ;)

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I believe if the customErrorMessage is null, then we can throw applicationImage error ... am i correct?

Comment: how can I access customErrorMesssage in applicationImage custom validator ? i have given something like this .... applicationImage(maxSize: MAX_SIZE,
            validator: {
                if (customErrorMessage == null) {
                    return ['nullable']
                }
            }
                        )  and it says No such property

Comment: guess what it worked...thanks a ton..krystian...i have implemented it as applicationImage(maxSize: MAX_SIZE,
         validator: {val, obj ->
            if (obj.customErrorMessage == null) {
                if (val == null) return ['nullable']

            }
        })

Comment: sorry krystian, came to know of accepting the answers, just now...so came back to accept your answer...cheers again

Answer (score 0):

```
applicationImage(maxSize: MAX_SIZE,
            validator: {val, obj ->
            if (obj.customErrorMessage == null) {
                if (val == null) return ['nullable']

            }
        })
```